# Как выстроить несколько блоков div в ряд по центру окна браузера?

Tags: html, css

При таком раскладе блоки стоят в ряд, но по левую сторону окна браузера (CSS прикрепила в комментарии, тк еще не разобралась как 2 кода публиковать :)

````
<main> 
   <div class="menu text stroke">
     <div class="menu-position">
       <a href="./Playlists.html"><p>PLAYLISTS</p></a>
     </div>
     <div class="menu-position">
       <a href="./LocalArtists.html"><p>LOCAL ARTISTS</p></a>
     </div>
     <div class="menu-position">
       <a href="./Shop.html"><p>SHOP</p></a>
     </div>
  </div>
</main>```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
.menu-position {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 10%;
    width: 30%;
    margin: 1%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Весь css не видно. Сделайте

```
.menu text stroke {
display:flex;
justify-content: center;
}
```

Либо для inline-block задайте text-align:center;